# Are pointers to any kind of variables possible?

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to know if it'd be possible (and if, how) to create a pointer of X value
Now, let's say I know which types would be possible to be assigned in this pointer.

For example, a pointer of X value (of course feel free to change the name of this value), that'd be able to point to variables of string, bool and a custom class

Comment: are you looking for void pointer

Comment: It's called `void *`, IIRC. But you'll have to cast in C++ (not in C, though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually what you describe is a bad idea.

`void*` works, for marginal values of works.  It throws out all type safety, requiring you to keep track of it.

Creating a root type sort of works, but it doesn't work for primitive types, and is rather intrusive.

A `boost::variant< bool*, std::string*, MyClass* >` is a variable that can contain a pointer to any one of these 3 types (`bool`, `std::string` or `MyClass`).  You will probably find it challenging to use, because it enforces type safety, and the syntax can get annoying.

Similarly, a pointer to `boost::variant< bool, std::string, MyClass >` may be what you want, but it doesn't let you point to `bool` variables you aren't fooling around with.

With full C++11 support, `union` can contain arbitrary types, together with an enum can let you do something very much like a `boost::variant`.  As a downside, this requires the thing you be pointed to be a `union`.  With or without full C++11 support, a union of pointers is reasonable.  In both cases, you'll have to track the type manually and keep it in sync.

What you really need to think about is "why am I asking this?", because as with many questions, the motivation matters.  You may not be asking the right question.

Comment: So using a `void` pointer would be the easiest to use but only "problem" with it would be the fact that I'd have to keep track of it?

Comment: @P.K. no, it wouldn't be the easiest.  Much of the annoyance in other cases is front-loading the cost of managing the type safety issues by actually managing them!  The `void*` solution is the one with the least front-loaded work, but the most bugs and problems down the road.

Comment: @Yakk I see. But then using `boost::variant` would be just easy by adding an object and assigning an adress to it, just like to a regular pointer? Minding the types of pointers allowed to it, of course

Comment: Nm, I found the tutorial for the usage of it, thanks for the help

Comment: @P.K. To extract the value, you'd call `get` -- see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic -- or use `apply_visitor`.  Note that `get( &variant )` is the query-and-get, while `get( variant )` throws on failure.

Answer (score 4):

I learned a new expression today, so I'm going to use it, "This is an XY question", You want to do X, so you think the solution is Y, therefore you ask how to do Y. You PROBABLY should ask how to do Y instead. It's a bit like you find your front wheel on the car punctured, and you go talk to the mechanic, but you don't ask "how do I fix a puncture", you ask "How do I undo a wheelnut", and only after you've removed all wheelnuts and the car has fallen over do you realize that you should have put a jack under the car to be able to get the wheel off without the car falling over...

Sure, there are void pointers and unions, that's no big deal. However, you still need to know what your pointer is actually pointing at, otherwise you'll have bloody mess.

So generally, in C++, you probably shouldn't do that.

What you should do is wrap your "thing" in another object, that knows what the content is, and can handle it. That way, you don't have some other thing maintainng state of what the object is and how to use it.

For example, we can have this:

```
class AnyThing
{
   public:
     virtual ~AnyThing();
     virtual std::string ToString() = 0; 
     ... // other things you want to do with your "things". 
};

class IntThing: public AnyThing 
{
     private:
        int value;

     public:
        virtual std::string ToString() { ... convert int to string ... }
};

class StringThing : public Anything
{
    private: 
       std::string value;
    public:
        virtual std::string ToString() { return value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [pointer to void](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/).

Comment: But it would usually be a bad idea.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the OP only wants it to be possible to point at specific types, not literally any type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pointer that can only be used to point at those three types, then I see three options:

1. Create a wrapper class for each type that derives from some base-class:

   ```
   class Thingy { protected: Thing() {} };

   class BoolThingy   : public Thingy { bool x; }
   class StringThingy : public Thingy { String x; }
   class CustomThingy : public Thingy { Custom x; }

   ...

   Thingy *p = new BoolThingy;
   ```
2. Create a smart-pointer class, overloading assignment operators that take `bool *`, `String *`, `Custom *`, and also overloading the `*` operator (although what that would do, I don't know!)
3. Use a variant class (e.g. `boost::variant`).

But with any of the options, it's not clear how such a thing would be useful...

Answer (score 1):

`void*` has the property to point to any data type. It actually works as a container or cubboard in which you put your variable of any data type and then pass the `void*` to a function.

You must know the data type of the data you passed, in order to use it.

For Example:

```
int main()
{
    int a;

    void *x=&a;

    func(x);

    ....

}


void func(void *argument)
{

   int i=*(int *)argument;

   ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the types before hand and they do not have constructors. Then you can use a union.

```
class CustomClass {};
union MyType
{
    char const*  a;
    bool         b;
    float        c;
};

MyType    stuff;
MyType*   ptrToStuff = &stuff;

int main()
{
    ptrToStuff->a = "Plop";
    ptrToStuff->b = false;
    ptrToStuff->c = 12.0;
}
```

Boost also has an ANY type.
You can store anything in it.

```
boost::any x = 12;
x = new CustomClass;
x = new std::string("Hi There");
x = std::string("Plop");  // even works without pointers.
```

Comment: Bah, don't leak resources in your answer.  :p

Comment: @Yakk: If you play with pointers. Then you need to manage the resources. Unfortunately there is not enough information about the resource in the question to decide who has ownership and thus weather it is even required to release anything.

Comment: I was just talking about your use of `new std::string`, followed on the next line by leaking it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pointer to any type (object, pointer, primitive type etc.) but you can not have a pointer to a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** you cannot have a pointer pointing at objects of unspecified type. The whole point of a pointer is that it points at objects of specific type. `int*x` points at an `int`, `A*a` points at an `A`.

What you can do, of course, is to have a variable of type `void*` that points at nothing at all (`void`), but *can hold any address*. If you somehow remember what it is the address of, then you can use a `static_cast<>` to cast to an appropriate pointer. Alternatively, you can use `dynamic_cast<>` to find out at run-time whether your `void*` points to a given type. This could be implemented as follows

```
struct AnyPointerWrapper
{
  struct null_pointer {};
  struct wrong_pointer_type {};

  AnyPointerWrapper() : ptr(0) {}

  AnyPointerWrapper(AnyPointerWrapper const&) = default;

  AnyPointerWrapper&operator=(AnyPointerWrapper const&) = default;

  template<typename T>
  explicit AnyPointerWrapper(T*p)
  : ptr(p) {}

  template<typename T>
  AnyPointerWrapper&operator=(T*p)
  { ptr=p; return*this; }

  bool is_null() const
  { return ptr==0; }

  template<typename T>
  bool is() const
  { return dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr) != 0; }

  template<typename T>
  T* pointer()
  {
     if(p==0) throw null_pointer;
     T*p = dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr);
     if(p==0) throw wrong_pointer_type;
     return p;
  }

private:
  void*ptr;
};
```

and used like this

```
int X;
AnyPointerWrapper a;
assert(a.is_null());
a = &X;
assert(a.is<int>());
int*p = a.pointer<int>();
```

(you can add more functionality including support for `const` pointers). **Note**, however, that the `dynamic_cast<>` is not trivial, i.e. incurs some performance penalty. Note also that `AnyPointerWrapper` is not a pointer: you cannot use the `->` operator to call a member function of the object whose address is stored in `AnyPointerWrapper::ptr`; it is merely a wrapper from which you can get an appropriate pointer.